# Mistake in proof: Symmetric group acting on group ring

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-rings

Let $G$ be finite group of order $n$ and $K$ be a field. The symmetric group on $G$, denoted by $S_G$ acts linearly on the group ring $K[G]$ by

$$\sigma\left(\sum_{g\in G}c_gg\right):=\sum_{g \in G}c_g\sigma(g) $$

The corresponding homomorphism
$$\rho:S_G\to GL(K[G])\cong GL_n(K)  $$
is, injective since $\rho(\sigma)=id$ implies $\sigma(g)=g$ for all $g\in G$.

Now if $K=\mathbb{F}_p$ this would imply that $n!=\# S_G$ divides $\# GL(K[G])=\#GL_n( \mathbb{F}_p)$, which is absolute nonsense since I didn't use that $G$ is a $p$-group or anything similar. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Presumably the mistake is in the unjustified statement "which is absolute nonsense"

Comment: (BTW this is an extremely complicated way to say "the symmetric group is isomorphic to the subgroup of $n \times n$ permutation matrices inside $GL_n(K)$ for all $K$.  In particular, the group structure of $G$ is completely irrelevant to what you've written.)

Comment: @JBL I guess I was confused that $n!$ really divides in $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ for every $p$. I guess there really was no mistake, thank you.

Comment: I agree that it's not obvious from the formula for $\# GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ without some thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mistake and as JBL says in the comments you don't use anything about the group structure on $G$. Here is a simpler argument: $S_n$ acts $K$-linearly and faithfully on $K^n$ by permuting the coordinates, for any field $K$ (even any commutative ring). This gives a canonical embedding of $S_n$ into $GL_n(K)$ as the subgroup of permutation matrices which, when $K$ is a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, establishes that $n!$ divides the order

$$|GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)| = q^{ {n \choose 2} } (q - 1)^n [n]_q!$$

of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$. Here

$$[n]_q! = \prod_{i=1}^n [i]_q = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{q^i - 1}{q - 1}$$

is the [$q$-factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog#%22Classical%22_q-theory). It is by no means obvious at first glance, just looking at these formulas, that this divisibility ought to hold. So, how can we prove it directly? We can work one prime at a time. If $p$ is a prime recall that $\nu_p(n)$ is the greatest exponent $k$ such that $p^k \mid n$. [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) tells us that

$$\nu_p(n!) = \sum_{k \ge 1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor$$

so to prove the divisibility we need to show that $\nu_p(|GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)|)$ is bigger than or equal to this for all primes $p$. I did this calculation recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4496512/232) so we can steal it: if $\gcd(p, q) = 1$ then we get

$$\nu_p(|GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)|) = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{d} \right\rfloor \nu_p(q^d - 1) + \sum_{k \ge 1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{dp^k} \right\rfloor$$

where $d = \text{ord}_p(q)$ is the smallest positive integer such that $q^d \equiv 1 \bmod p$. In particular $d \le p-1$ and $\nu_p(q^d - 1) \ge 1$ which gives

$$\nu_p(|GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)|) \ge \sum_{k \ge 0} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{(p-1)p^k} \right\rfloor$$

and the desired inequality is clear since $\frac{1}{p-1} > \frac{1}{p}$. If $p \mid q$ then $\nu_p(|GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)|) \ge {n \choose 2}$ which is much larger than what we need.

This expression on the RHS can be interpreted as $\log_p$ of the order of the "Sylow $p$-subgroup" of $GL_n(\mathbb{Q})$, in the sense that every $p$-subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{Q})$ embeds into it (which means it controls how large a finite subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{Q})$ can be). See Serre's *[Bounds for the orders of the finite subgroups of $G(k)$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.0346)* for much more on this.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It is kind of funny that the group-theoretical proof that $n! \mid \# GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is way shorter than the direct computation.

Comment: @Ben: there are a few other divisibility results like that too. For example showing that $n!^m m!$ divides $(nm)!$. The computation one prime at a time is probably doable but the argument that proceeds by constructing an appropriate subgroup of $S_{nm}$ (nice exercise if you haven't done it) is to my mind much cleaner and faster.

Comment: Hey t0rajir0u, long time no see.  Hope all's well.